Is this graph planar? If so, how do I number the vertices cyclic order?
Question
Let us be given the following graph:
Graph with 6 vertices, where $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$, $v_5$ are twisted in a spiral
Also link in Desmos: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ebxkvrg5wz
Description of the graph:
The graph consists of 6 vertices. 1 vertex $v$ is located in the $(0,0)$ center of the system, and the remaining vertices $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$, $v_4$, $v_5$ are on the side.
There are edges:
$(v_1, v)$
$(v_2, v)$
$(v_3, v)$
$(v_4, v)$
$(v_5 , v)$
The edges twist into a spiral, infinitely approaching (0,0). In the example in Desmos, the spiral ends before reaching the end, but we will assume that the spiral approaches $(0,0)$ for an infinitely long time. The edges do not intersect with each other
I have two questions:

Is this graph planar?
If so, how do I number the vertices in a cyclic order?


Some thoughts
It seems to me that in this example it is impossible to number the vertices in a cyclic order unambiguously.
But then this example should break the five-color theorem. Quote from the proof on Wiki:
So now look at those five vertices $v_1​, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5$ that were adjacent to $v$ in cyclic order (which depends on how we write $G$).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_color_theorem.

Edit 1
I know that this graph can be colored using two colors. But what if this subgraph is found in a large graph where all vertices $v_1, ..., v_5$ already have different colors?
The five-color theorem says that in such a situation we must number the vertices in cyclic order (This is important!) Like in this picture 
Then construct a subgraph $G_{1,3}$ consisting of the vertex colors $v_1$ and $v_3$.
There are two possible situations

If there is no path between $v_1$ and $v_3$ in graph $G_{1,3}$, then we can recolor the vertices in the component containing $v_1$ but not containing $v_3$.

If $v_1$ and $v_3$ are in the same connectivity component, then $v_2$ and $v_4$ cannot be in the same connectivity component in the $G_{2,4}$ subgraph.  Let's do a similar repainting, as we did in paragraph 2.


I repeat once again: the numbering order of the vertices is important to us. If, for example, we number in the order $v_1, v_3, v_2, v_4, v_5$, then it may happen that $v_1$ and $v_3$ will lie in the same component, and $v_2$ and $v_4$ will lie in the same connectivity component. Then it will not be possible to do a repaint according to the theorem. An example
Аnd yes, I know that the above example with spirals should not completely break the proof of the five-color theorem. You just need to figure out how to number the vertices correctly.

The graph is 2 colourable. v is red, the other vertices are green. No edge connects vertices of the same colour

@user24142, this sounds interesting, but I don't really understand why we can assume that the vertices are not connected? the spirals are continuous and I think reach the vertex at $v$ at the point $(0,0)$.

Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your answer. Yes, this graph can be colored with 2 colors, but if such a subgraph is found in some large one, then it seems that problems will arise, which I wrote about below

you're misunderstanding how the order of vertices is determined. Its not by the manner in which the edges between the centre and its attached vertices are presented, its by the set of all the edges of the graph. For instance, if you have no edges besides the five shown, any order is valid. If there is an edge between $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ and $v_5$ and $v_1$, then there are two acceptable orders, clockwise and anticlockwise. Further, embeddings like the one your are proposing are known to be unnecessary.

It is planar. When considering a graph, the way you draw the edges is irrelevant, the only thing that matters is the connections. The graph you are considering is exactly the graph $K_{1,5}$ otherwise known as a star with $5$ leaves. i.e. this graph


I think it is important to correctly number the vertices in the proof that is on the wiki. The whole proof is based on the fact that we specifically know that the numbered vertices go in a cyclic order.
If we number the vertices in any order, we can get a situation where the two paths that we build in the subgraph $G_{1,3}$ and $G_{2,4}$ may not intersect and we will not get the contradiction that is needed to prove the last point in the five-color theorem.

And @Bruno’s drawing proves it’s both planar and 2-colorable, as are all $K_{1,n}$ and indeed all forests.

@Bruno Andrades, The graph from the example is indeed a graph like in your picture, however we can randomly number the vertices in the sequence $v_1$, $v_3$, $v_2$, $v_4$, $v_5$. And it can break the proof
